# Groovy map : get the count of value that a key holds

Tags: groovy

I have a map,

```
 def map= [name:[Vin], email:[vin@gmail.com], phone:[9988888888], jobTitle:[SE]]
```

i want get the total number of values that a key holds

for ex,

key `name`  can have many values like `[name:[Vin,Hus,Rock]`  how to do it programatically?

```
def count = map.name.size() //gives wrong answer
```

Comment: Is this the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18735217/groovy-hashmap-get-the-value-count-from-a-map ? What do you mean _"def count = map.name.size() //gives wrong answer"_  WHat answer do you expect?  What answer do you get? I suspect you asked the wrong question here with bad examples, then re-asked another question later on with better examples. Editing the question was probably a better route to take.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following code to get a list of size for all key.

```
def map= [name:['Vin',''], email:['vin@gmail.com'], phone:['9988888888'], jobTitle:['SE']]
map.collect{it.value.size()}
```

Output:

```
 [2, 1, 1, 1]
```

I think map.name.size() should work fine too in groovy.

Comment: map.name.size() gives me value 3 the count of total character in name

Comment: The example shown in answer shows 1,1,1 for email, phone, jobTitle which contains one value only and i tried this  map."keyName".size() syntax as well which works fine for me. Can you post some more example?

Answer (score 1):

```
def map= [name :['Vin', 'abc', 'xyz'], 
          email:['vin@gmail.com'], 
          phone:[9988888888], 
          jobTitle:['SE']]

//Spread operator to get size of each value
assert map.values()*.size == [3, 1, 1, 1]

//Implicit spread
assert map.values().size == [3, 1, 1, 1]

//use size() to get the size of the values collection
assert map.values().size() == 4

//Values
assert map.values() as List == [['Vin', 'abc', 'xyz'], 
                                ['vin@gmail.com'], [9988888888], ['SE']]
```