# groovy Hashmap - get the value count from a map

Tags: groovy

my following code

```
def traineeDetails = session.traineeDetailsForAuto
```

on printing gives:

```
traineeDetails = [name:[Hus, Vin], email:[hus@gmail.com, vin@gmail.com], phone:[9908877654, 9987655432], jobTitle:[SE, ST]]

def count = traineeDetails.name.size()  gives correct value =2
```

but when the map key contains one value

```
 def traineeDetails = session.traineeDetailsForAuto
```

on printing gives:

```
 traineeDetails = [name:Hus, email:hus@gmail.com, phone:9987766543, jobTitle:SE]

 def count= traineeDetails.name.size() gives wrong answer 3 which is the total number of character in name
```

but here i need to get total count of value that the key name holds..

how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to mix types in a map, then you're going to need to check the type:

```
def count = traineeDetails.name.with { it instanceof Collection ? it.size() : 1 }
```

Using your examples, it works fine:

```
traineeDetails = [name:['Hus', 'Vin'], email:['hus@gmail.com', 'vin@gmail.com'], phone:['9908877654', '9987655432'], jobTitle:['SE', 'ST']]
count = traineeDetails.name.with { it instanceof Collection ? it.size() : 1 }

assert count == 2

traineeDetails = [name:'Hus', email:'hus@gmail.com', phone:'9987766543', jobTitle:'SE']
count = traineeDetails.name.with { it instanceof Collection ? it.size() : 1 }

assert count == 1
```

Can you provide actual non-working examples?

Comment: @monda what answer do you get then?  Added the code to prove it does work with the examples you're giving...  Can you provide an example which fails?